# How to make pgfplots vertical labels have proper hyperref erence box?

Tags: hyperref, pgfplots, rotating, units

PGFPlots and hyperref don't seem to play well together for vertical text. For example, the ylabel (which is vertical) shows its hyperref box in the middle of nowhere instead of at the position and direction of the vertical label.

Does anybody know a workaround?

(Note two things: the hyperref box works well for rotatebox and for horizontal labels)

[image: wrong vertical label]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}  
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{\href{http://www.google.com}{hello}}bye
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[xlabel = {\href{http://www.google.com}{Time}},  ylabel = {\href{http://www.google.com}{Length}}] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Although Jake's answer (and Martin's) does the job, the problem persists for "units" part of the label. (I should have posted the full problem in my question instead of a simplification). As in the picture and code below, see how it seem not trivial to rotate the units part and also make it appear the expected location (after the end of the word "Length"):

[image: units with link not rotated]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\begin{document}
A plot with units:\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y label style={rotate=-90}, x unit = {\href{http://www.google.com}{\mathrm{s}}}, y unit = {\href{http://www.google.com}{\mathrm{m}}}, xlabel = {Time}, ylabel = {\rotatebox{90}{Length}}, title = {Axis}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rotate the label in `pgfplots` by using `y label style={rotate=-90}` to get the `hyperref` box right, and then provide the label using a `rotatebox`. With this workaround, the `hyperref` box has the correct size and placement.

(I also added the `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}`, which improves the placement of the axis labels. It's not necessary for the solution, though)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
  xlabel = {\href{http://www.google.com}{Time}},
  ylabel = {\rotatebox{90}{\href{http://www.google.com}{Length}}},
  y label style={rotate=-90}
] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots axis with vertical hyperref links]

---

In order to make this work with the `units` library, you can redefine one of the `units` library's macros that takes care of assembling the label and unit. The following code checks whether we're defining the label for the y axis, and if we are, it encloses the whole label string (i.e. label and unit) in a `rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\makeatletter
\def\pgfplots@label@units#1{
    \if#1y\rotatebox{90}{\fi%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgfplots/#1label}{\pgfplots@loc@TMPa}%
    \pgfplots@loc@TMPa\space\pgfplots@label@units@@{#1}%
    \if#1y}\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y label style={rotate=-90},
  x unit = {\href{http://www.google.com}{\mathrm{s}}},
  y unit = {\href{http://www.google.com}{\mathrm{m}}},
  xlabel = {Time}, ylabel = {Length}, title = {Axis}]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: linked unit]

Comment: great works for answer of the question. However, I should have posted my full problem. Which was the case where the hyperlink was in the "y unit = {\\href{...}{m}". I'll edit the question just to add the picture.

Comment: thanks, also if you add `\pgfplotsset{y label style={rotate=-90}}` in the header (e.g. before `\makeatletter
`, you can use the `axis` environment as if this bug never existed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the underlying rotation code of PGF/TikZ doesn't rotate the extra `href` box `hyperref` creates. One workaround for this is to manually rotate it using `\rotatebox` and a `\phantom` content. The `\phantom` macro creates a box with the same dimensions as the content without printing anything.
The `\llap` macro is then used to make it lap over the real content without pushing it to the side. Normally `\rlap` should be used but because of the 90degr turn it must be lapped to the left side instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{\href{http://www.google.com}{hello}}bye
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel = {\href{http://www.google.com}{Time}},  ylabel = {%
             \llap{\rotatebox{90}{\href{http://www.google.com}{\phantom{Length}}}}%
             Length}] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This isn't perfect. The resulting `href` box is not 100% at its correct horizontal position, but it is close and IMHO good enough.

[image: Result]

You might want sent this to the author of `pgfplots` and maybe also to the one of `hyperref`.