# Matching Rotated \hyperref in arbitrarily rotated x-label in Pgfplots 

Tags: hyperref, pgfplots, rotating

Similar to this question: [How to make pgfplots vertical labels have proper hyperref erence box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13364/how-to-make-pgfplots-vertical-labels-have-proper-hyperref-erence-box) Except, that I am trying to get hyperref working with angled rotated x-axis labels:
[image: plot]
[image: plot2]

Got it working, thanks to @Jake.

[image: fin]

**Update**: Got it sorted with href. Thanks.

```
\newcommand{\nenameref}[1]{\noexpand\nameref{{#1}}}
\newcommand{\nehref}[1]{\noexpand\href{{#1}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\labellist{{"\nehref{www.google.com}{google}","\nenameref{testtwo}","reallylonglabel"}},
```

Comment: There was a similar post with hyperref rotation stuff, perhaps this is of use [how-to-make-pgfplots-vertical-labels-have-proper-hyperref-erence-box](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13364/how-to-make-pgfplots-vertical-labels-have-proper-hyperref-erence-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all the tick labels in a `rotatebox` by using the `\ticklabel` key (instead of `\ticklabels`) and defining the references in a list with `\noexpand` so they survive all the processing. You should use an `anchor` that is equivalent to the rotation of the labels, to avoid getting an offset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section{the beginning}
This is a test.\label{test} \\
This is \nameref{test}. 
\section{second section}
Test two \label{testtwo}

\newcommand{\nenameref}[1]{\noexpand\nameref{{#1}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\labellist{{"\nenameref{test}","\nenameref{testtwo}","reallylonglabel"}},
\begin{axis}[xtick={1,...,3},
  xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\labellist[\tick-1]}\rotatebox{65}{\pgfmathresult}},
  x tick label style={anchor=65}]
\addplot+[only marks,
  error bars/.cd,
    y dir=both,
    y explicit,
    error bar style={line width=2pt},
    error mark options={
      rotate=90,
      red,
      mark size=8pt,
      line width=2pt}
]
coordinates {
(3,1) +- (0,0.35665)
(2,1) +- (0,-0.35048)
(1,1) +- (0,0.150255)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots with rotate tick labels]

Comment: oooo that looks good. I will get right on it. Many thanks. As always.