# Hyperlink a rotated nodepart

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, nodes, links

I would like to have the entire node part a link. But, it seems that once you rotate, `hyperref` has issues. The reference below say to place the rotated content in the hyperlink, but not sure how to do that when using `Tikz`'s `nodepart`:

[image]

### Notes:

- The links work fine if `\def\VerticalText{}` is commented.
- Ideally, I'd prefer the entire rectangular region to be a link, but having just the text would be acceptable.

### References

- [How to rotate hyperlink with text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30266/how-to-rotate-hyperlink-with-text)
- [How to make pgfplots vertical labels have proper hyperref erence box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13364/how-to-make-pgfplots-vertical-labels-have-proper-hyperref-erence-box)
- [Hyperref box does not obey slant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237063/hyperref-box-does-not-obey-slant)

### Code:

```
\def\VerticalText{}% <--- All links work if comment this out.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\ifdefined\VerticalText
    \tikzset{My Rotate/.style={rotate=90}}%
\else
    \tikzset{My Rotate/.style={}}%
\fi

\tikzset{Node Label Style/.style={
    anchor=south, 
    above, 
    align=center,
    }
}

\tikzset{Rectangle Split Style/.style={
        rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3, 
        My Rotate,
        anchor=south,
        thick, fill=gray!10,
    }
}
\tikzset{Node Part Style/.style={draw, minimum width=2.1cm, align=center}}


\newcommand*{\GoogleLink}{\href{http://www.google.com}{\shortstack{Google \\ Web Site}}}%


\begin{document}

This multi-line link works: \GoogleLink

The link in the title also work:

\bigskip
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[Rectangle Split Style] (MyNode) at (0,0) [Node Part Style]  
        {\nodepart{one}   \GoogleLink %% <-- This link does NOT work if \VerticalText is defined
         \nodepart{two}   \shortstack{Yahoo \\ Web Site} 
         \nodepart{three} \shortstack{TeX.SE \\ Web Site}
        };
        
\ifdefined\VerticalText
    \coordinate (Title Location) at (MyNode.east);
\else
    \coordinate (Title Location) at (MyNode.north);
\fi

%% This link works fine:
\node [Node Label Style] at (Title Location)  {\GoogleLink};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would like to declare a horizontal version of `rectangle split`. Then the remaining is not Ti*k*Z anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
\href{<www-Link>}{\tikz{<....>}}
```

or

```
\node [<styles>] 
{\rotatebox{90}{<...>}
\nodepart{two}  \rotatebox{90}{<...>}
\nodepart{three} \rotatebox{90}{<...>}
};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\newcommand*{\GoogleLink}{\href{http://www.google.com}{\shortstack{Google \\ Web Site}}}%
\newcommand*{\YahooLink}{\href{http://www.google.com}{\shortstack{Yahoo \\ Web Site}}}%
\newcommand*{\TeXLink}{\href{http://www.google.com}{\shortstack{TeX.SE \\ Web Site}}}%
\begin{document}
\tikzset{Rectangle Split Style/.style={
rectangle split, 
rectangle split horizontal, 
rectangle split parts=3, 
anchor=south, align=left, 
draw=black, thick, fill=gray!10,
text width=2em, minimum size=2cm,
},
}

\newcommand\AllOneLink{%
\tikz{\node [Rectangle Split Style] 
{\rotatebox{90}{All}   
\nodepart{two}  \rotatebox{90}{one}
\nodepart{three} \rotatebox{90}{Link}
};
}}

\href{http://www.google.com}{\AllOneLink}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [Rectangle Split Style] 
{\rotatebox{90}{\GoogleLink}   
\nodepart{two}  \rotatebox{90}{\YahooLink}
\nodepart{three} \rotatebox{90}{\TeXLink}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```